# Login page authentication with Httpclient and navigate to next page

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to login to [This website](http://postimage.org/profile.php) site which has username and password  authentication and a login button. Is this code correct for login authentication. This code will help me navigate to next page? When I try to get the url of the navigated page it returns the login in page url.

```java
String UrlLink ="http://postimage.org/profile.php";
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(UrlLink);              
        List<NameValuePair> login = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "xxxxxx"));
        login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "yyyyyyy"));
        login.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Login", "Login"));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(login));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.v("Document", httpPost.getURI().toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Error", e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: According to the `HttpPost.getURI()` [javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpRequestBase.html#getURI()), this method will only return the original (unchanged) request URI. What is the value of `code`? You will also have to check the `response` object for other information from the server.

Comment: I am getting the status code for respoce as 200

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the server-side PHP codes are sending a `302` redirect header upon successful login, you can add these codes to your `doInBackground()` method to trigger a client-side redirect (if you are using HTTP Client 4.1+).

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
client.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());
```