# How to login a site if it has username and password with HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am getting the html page content using HttpURLConnection like the below code. If a site has login in credentials then how I should pass URL with username and password. How I can pass URL with username and password for the below site for login.

```
String UrlLink1 ="http://postimage.org/profile.php";
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {   
        URL url = new URL(UrlLink1);
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.connect();
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        String newUrl=urlConnection.getURL().toString();
        doc = Jsoup.connect(UrlLink1).get();
        Elements docEle = doc.select(".gallery a");
        Log.v("Document", docEle.toString());
        }

    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Error", e.toString());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Login page authentication with Httpclient and navigate to next page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883435/login-page-authentication-with-httpclient-and-navigate-to-next-page)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class DummyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    private String username = null;
    private String password = null;

    public DummyAsyncTask(String username, String password)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urlStr)
    {
        if (username != null && password != null)
        {
            // TODO : Do something with those credentials
        }

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(UrlLink1);
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();
            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            String newUrl=urlConnection.getURL().toString();
            doc = Jsoup.connect(urlStr[0]).get();
            Elements docEle = doc.select(".gallery a");
            Log.v("Document", docEle.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
DummyAsyncTask task = new DummyAsyncTask("myUsername", "SecretPassword");
task.execute("http://postimage.org/profile.php");
```

Comment: No still it is not login in. If I print the newUrl it is same as login page. I want the redirected page url and html page content of redirected page. I am trying it for 2 days plz help. Username of the link is xaeroprasad and pass ramesh88